# trying to cast an integer to NSNumber - getting strange numbers instead

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

"rowNumber" gets logged at like: **79050688**. "rowNumberAsInt" gets logged as a number under **16**.  How can I convert my int properly?

```
-(int)randomNumberGenerator{

int rowNumberAsInt;
NSNumber *rowNumber;

randomNumberPool = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:16];

while (![randomNumberPool containsObject:rowNumber]) {
    rowNumberAsInt = (arc4random() % 16);
    rowNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:rowNumberAsInt];
    [randomNumberPool addObject:rowNumber];     
}

NSLog(@"random rowNumber: %d ", rowNumber);
NSLog(@"random rowNumberAsInt: %d ", rowNumberAsInt);
return rowNumberAsInt;
```

}

Answer (score 6):

You cannot print a NSNumber like it's an int,because it's not an int, but an object wrapping an int.Use the %@ format specifier instead:

```
NSLog(@"random rowNumber: %@ ", rowNumber);
```

Or use the intValue method:

```
NSLog(@"random rowNumber: %d ", [rowNumber intValue]);
```

Comment: @user465001 if this answers your question, please accept the answer (or NSGod's one) by checking the green mark next to it, so that other users will know you don't expect further explanations anymore and mark this question as resolved (and by the way it will give you more reputation points in SO)

Comment: @AliSoftware they are both good answers. Which one would you choose?

Comment: That is up to you, I would say the one that seems the better explanation to you… even if in this case I agree that they are pretty much the same ;) but just pick one (even arbitrarily as they are equivalent) to mark the question as resolved!

Answer (score 3):

`NSString` provides `%@` as a format to allow printing of objects. You should change the line:

```
NSLog(@"random rowNumber: %d ", rowNumber);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"random rowNumber: %@ ", rowNumber);
```

The top line as is will print the memory address of the `NSNumber` object. In practice, this will likely be a random number, but not in the way you intended. ;-)

Comment: You should also explain that the value printed with NSNumber is the pointer value (memory address of the NSNumber object).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations NSGOD and Macmade.